Trying to access an array in a .cs file to another page in C#
Created an array in a file called tablearray.cs. I want to use it on another page. getting Table.Rate is inaccessible due to protection level.
First i have an array below is a part of it.
namespace testarray
{
    public  partial class Table
    {
        double[,] Rate = new double[,]
        {
            { 0.25,    0.384615385, 0.153846154 },
            { 0.255,   0.395348837, 0.15503876 },
            { 0.26,    0.40625,     0.15625 },
            { 0.265,   0.417322835, 0.157480315 },
            { 0.27,    0.428571429, 0.158730159 },

I placed the following code in the same file
public Tuple<double, double, double> GetRates(double input)
{

    double PercentToGive = 0;
    double ValueStore = 0;
    double ValueAdmin = 0;

    foreach (int x in Rate)
    {
        if (Rate[x, 0] == input)
        {
            PercentToGive = Rate[x, 0];
            ValueStore = Rate[x, 1];
            ValueAdmin = Rate[x, 2];
            break;


        }
    }

and than in the page to call this
Tuple<double, double, double> resultTuple = Table.GetRates(Convert.ToDouble(txtInput.Text));
I get this error
CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Table.GetRates(double)'
Then i copied the Getrates to the same page that i call the function on.
` public Tuple<double, double, double> GetRates(double input)
{
 double PercentToGive = 0;
 double ValueStore = 0;
 double ValueAdmin = 0;

 foreach (int x in Table.Rate)
 {
     if (Rate[x, 0] == input)
     {
         PercentToGive = Rate[x, 0];
         ValueStore = Rate[x, 1];
         ValueAdmin = Rate[x, 2];
         break;


     }`

Table.Rate is inaccessable due to its protection level.
I have looked online and can't find the answer

That "protection level" error is because you didn't specify an access level, so that defaults to private. And then it still needs an instance (unless you make it static as well)

You need to create an instance of the class which contains the method.
Table t = new Table();
Tuple<double, double, double> resultTuple = t.GetRates(Convert.ToDouble(txtInput.Text));


You could make what @Chad said, or also make Rate and GetRate static and public:
public class Table
{
  public static readonly double[,] Rate = new double[0,0];
  public static Tuple<double, double, double> GetRates(double input);
}

Also could you a getter:
public class Table
{
  public static double[,] Rate => new double[0,0];
  public static Tuple<double, double, double> GetRates(double input);
}

